# Primery key в регулярных выражениях RegEx

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Допустими у меня есть строка с элементами разделенных запятыми "el1 ,el2, el3" , регулярное выражение для этой строки [\w]+,[\w]* . Как написать выражение для такой же строки но с проверкой что только у одного элемента в начале есть строка "primary key"?

Comment: не совсем понятный вопрос. покажи пример, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться. несколько строк и желаемый результат

Comment: "PK el1 ,el2, el3" - TRUE - один елемент с строкой PK. 
"PK el1 ,PK el2, el3" - FALSE - больше одного елемента с с строкой PK. 
"el1 ,el2, el3" - FALSE  - нет елементов с строкой PK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*PK\s+\w)((PK\s(?!.*PK\s+\w))?\s*\w+\s*(,|$))+$
```

Тест на [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wIb14E/1)

```
^                      # Начало строки
(?=.*PK\s+\w)          # Где то в строке должен быть PK с пробелом и буквой после него
(                      # Начало группы описывающий элемент списка
 (PK\s(?!.*PK\s+\w))?  # Может быть PK. Если есть - то после него нигде PK больше нет
 \s*\w+\s*             # прочие буквы и пробелы
 (,|$)                 # после них или запятая или конец строки
)+                     # группа должна повторятся 1 и более раз
$                      # конец строки
```